# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nets' (I already have nets in folder)

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

import os

from object_detection.utils import label_map_util

from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as viz_utils

from object_detection.builders import model_builder

### **ERROR**

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in

2 from object_detection.utils import label_map_util

3 from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as viz_utils

----> 4 from object_detection.builders import model_builder

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py in

```
 33 from object_detection.meta_architectures import rfcn_meta_arch

 34 from object_detection.meta_architectures import ssd_meta_arch
```

---> 35 from object_detection.models import faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_feature_extractor as frcnn_inc_res

```
 36 from object_detection.models import faster_rcnn_inception_v2_feature_extractor as frcnn_inc_v2

 37 from object_detection.models import faster_rcnn_nas_feature_extractor as frcnn_nas
```

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\object_detection\models\faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_feature_extractor.py in

```
 26 
 27 from object_detection.meta_architectures import faster_rcnn_meta_arch
```

---> 28 from nets import inception_resnet_v2

```
 29 

 30 slim = tf.contrib.slim
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nets'

Answer (score 0):

In the `models/research` directory, run the following commands

```
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py .
python -m pip install .
```

Then finally test the installation by running  `python object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf2_test.py`

If you are using Tensorflow version 1.X, just replace `tf2` with `tf1` in the installation and testing commands
[Source](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2.md)

Comment: After cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py . 
ERROR: 'cp' is not recognized as an internal or external command.


When i used COPY instead of cp,
ERROR: The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Comment: Run the above commands in windows power shell